# Private "Parents" content for school site

Tags: plugins

I'm developing a school site which is 90% public with no registration.  We want a private area for parents only which will show the parents phone directory, etc.  We don't want each individual parent to register for this, but would prefer to create a "parent" role with a single password to communicate to all parents.

Can someone please point me to a good plugin or approach to accomplish this goal?

Comment: You could just use a multisite and use a separate site for that. Assign members manually, require a log-in, and you’re done.

Comment: Didn't think of that.  Could the 2nd site share the template of the main site, or would there be two templates to maintain?

Comment: Both can, but don’t have to, use the same theme and plugins.

Comment: You could do this with very basic PHP. Create a login form that when submitted creates a session (if the correct username and password are entered). Then in the pages you want to be parent only, check this session is active. If so show the page if not redirect to login page. Shouldn't take more than a few hours for a PHP dev to implement something like this for you.